# SWR - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, swr

I'm trying to use SWR for fetching data but I'm getting this error. Not sure why this is happening, though it works fine with use effect hook.

[image]

[image]

This is the json data where it is fetching from -

```
{
  "dashboards": {
    "posts": 5,
    "likes": 5,
    "followers": 5,
    "followings": 5
  }
}
```

Comment: The `data` is empty at first and you use an async-await function to populate it. You need to check before/after the `if (error) { ... }`  block that the `data` is empty or not `if (!data) { ... }` and show a loading or something before it is populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `optional chaining` see if that works:

```js
<p>
{data?.posts}
</p>
<p>
{data?.likes}
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, It does works! Can you possibly help me out with the explanation of why does it works?

Comment: In javascript when you try to access a property from an undefined object , your app crashes . with optional chaining , js wont get crashed .